# Capture result of ImageMagick compare to a variable

Tags: bash

I am using a software called ImageMagick, that has command line inputs to do photo comparisons and output a value.
I want to save that output value to a specific variable for further analysis. 
How would I do that?
Here is the command I would run in command line:

```
compare -metric MSE Picture1.jpg Picture2.jpg difference.png
```

This will compare the pixel differences between picture 1 and picture 2. Save it as difference and output a number of the difference. If identical it will be 0.
I want to be able to capture that value in terms of a variable.

Comment: This is a really basic operation in shell scripting. You obviously need to start by reading a tutorial.

Comment: See: [How to set a variable equal to the output from a command in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/3776858)

Comment: In shell scripting it's important to distinguish between a command's [stdout] _output_ and its _exit code_, which are separate aspects. With the benefit of hindsight: what you're looking for is the exit code.

Answer (score 7):

Worked for me:

`variable=$(compare -metric MSE Picture1.jpg Picture2.jpg difference.png 2>&1)`

or

`variable=$(compare -metric MSE Picture1.jpg Picture2.jpg null: 2>&1)`

Answer (score 3):

As noted in a comment by [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams), **`compare` actually reports the similarity status via its *exit code***, not via its stdout output.

Ignacio, in his own answer, also mentions that

- the most recent command's exit code is reported in special variable `$?`
- it's worth *saving* that exit code in a variable right away, so that subsequent commands don't overwrite it.

Also, exit code `0` indicates that images are *similar*, not *identical*.

Here's a code snippet that shows how to save the exit code and handle it subsequently:

```
compare -metric MSE Picture1.jpg Picture2.jpg difference.png # add >/dev/null for no output
ec=$?  # save exit code
case $ec in  # evaluate exit code
  0)
    echo "images are similar"
    ;;
  1)
    echo "images are dissimilar"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "an unexpected error occured"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Use command substitution.

```
variable=$(compare -metric MSE Picture1.jpg Picture2.jpg difference.png)
```

Comment: That's what I thought they were asking as well, but then ["The compare program returns 2 on error otherwise 0 if the images are similar or 1 if they are dissimilar."](http://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php)

Answer (score 1):

The result of a command will always be in `$?`. Make sure to save that value in another variable before executing another command or it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Or use backticks . AKA , command [substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

```
variable=`compare -metric MSE Picture1.jpg Picture2.jpg difference.png`

echo "$variable"
```

Comment: This should be comment on [Barmar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36658287/45375). While the backtick syntax works fine in this simple case, 
you should mentions its drawbacks compared to the modern `$(...)` syntax.